# What is different between magento extension and rest api?

Tags: magento, magento2

What is different between magento extension and rest api?
What is the use of mageto extension and api file?
I am beginner in magento.Anyone plese help me.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Rest API is magento feature to provide us facility to get and set data in magento from third party applications using Rest API.  In Magento Rest API there are many functions to get Products data, Customers Data, Orders Data etc. You can check documentation using the below link:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Magento extensions are third party modules that we install to enhance magento by default functionality like ajax add to cart OR add new feature in magento like reward point etc.

Comment: Thank You!! I have an another query to ask you. Do you Know how linnlive works are access Magento using Rest API or Extension?? Can you Explain about?

Comment: For that you need to install linnlive extension in your magento installation.  https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/linnlive-integration-1.html

Comment: You need to create Soap API  user to connect that with in your linnlive account

Comment: Thank you for kind reply...... So, Which one is used in linnlive whether REST API or Extension?? Because i have to create concept like a Linnlive ??